# The separation of lanthanum oxide and chromium oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, rare-earth-elements

I have encountered a problem. How can I separate the alloy of lanthanum oxide and chromium oxide? I attempted to dissolve them in concentrated sulfuric acid with heating, but it didn't work. If I had dissolved them, I would then have added oxalic acid to the solution, and afterwards, lanthanum oxalate precipitate would have formed while chromium remained in the solution.

Comment: Try dilute Hydrochloric acid

Comment: @Waylander maybe. If the oxide has been annealed at high temperature, which is often the case with commercial Cr2O3, then any dilutecacid or alkali won't work. See https://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Chromium(III)_oxide#Handling. We would then need something like what I found below.

Answer (score 3):

Lanthanum oxide is soluble in dilute aqueous acids but chromic oxide may not be (depending on how it was processed). In a mixture the chromic oxide may inhibit dissolution of the otherwise more soluble lanthanum oxide. [You need to:](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-anyone-know-a-way-to-solve-Cr2O3)

> Chromium(III) oxide (Cr2O3) can be reactively dissolved with sulfuric acid (~85 wt%; H2SO4/Cr2O3 ≥ 6 wt/wt) mixed with perchloric acid (HClO4/Cr2O3 ≈ ½ wt/wt) by ~175 ºC (≤ 4h; under reflux).

Under these conditions the lanthanum oxide will be dissolved too. So this would get everything dissolved.

Lanthanum oxalate may remain soluble in strongly acidic media (reacts to form oxalic acid and the lanthanum salt of the stronger acid).  With the chromium apparently oxidized to Cr(VI), you may want to dilute and neutralize the solution before applying the oxalic acid; this would give the lanthanum oxalate precipitate with chromate remaining in solution. Note that Cr(VI) is considered hazardous and carcinogenuc material.

Comment: Not only hazardous but _carcinogenic_ ;)